# file sourcing within cgi failed

Tags: python, permissions, cgi

My cgi file:

```
#!/bin/sh -f
source /Users/sfma/sastbx/build/setpaths_all.sh
python processQuery.py
```

Then "Internal Server Error" arises. I checked the error_log, and it says:

```
 [Thu Jun 23 15:02:39.809441 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 1327] [client ::1:52131]     AH01215: /Users/sfma/sastbx/build/bin/libtbx.path_utility: line 63: /Users/sfma/sastbx/build/../../Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python: Permission denied: /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/web.cgi, referer: http://localhost/modelRetrieval/query.html
```

Remove the `source` statement, it works fine. But I need to source this file for further use.

**Edit**
According to the error message, I think the error may be due to the python permission.

```
#!/bin/sh -f
#python processQuery.py   #this works fine
/Users/sfma/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python processQuery.py    #this does not work. Permission denied.
```

This really puzzles me because `/Users/sfma/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python` is exactly the python I'm using:

```
$which python 
/Users/sfma/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem.

Since `python` works fine while `/Users/sfma/Library/Enthought/canopy_64bit/User/bin/python` leads to a problem, I hard coded some variables in files libtbx.path_utility and sastbx.python to "python" instead of what they used to be: "/Users/sfma/sastbx/build/../../Library/Enthought/canopy_64bit/User/bin/python"

**Update**
The reason why `/Users/sfma/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python` is permission denied is that _www is now allowed to visit my Library folder. Check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/33027/apache-isnt-chmod-755-enough-to-set-up-symlink-or-alias-on-apache-httpd-on-mac). After making that directory available to all, this problem is finally solved.